# Why is Synchronous SQLAlchemy Session Faster than Asynchronous in FastAPI

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am working with two versions of a FastAPI application: one using an asynchronous connection to a SQLAlchemy database and the other using a synchronous connection. Surprisingly, I'm observing that the synchronous version significantly outperforms the asynchronous one during performance tests.

**Setup:**

- FastAPI Version: 0.95.1
- SQLAlchemy Version: 2.0.19
- Database: SQLite
- PyNest version: 0.1.0

**Performance Test Results:**

- Asynchronous Version: ~500 seconds for 1000 requests
- Synchronous Version: 0.72 seconds for 1000 requests

**Asynchronous Session Initialization:**

```py
class Config:

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_async_engine("sqlite+aiosqlite:///finance.db", connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})
        self.SessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(self.engine)
        self.Base = Base

    async def create_all(self):
        async with self.engine.begin() as conn:
            await conn.run_sync(self.Base.metadata.create_all)

    async def drop_all(self):
        async with self.engine.begin() as conn:
            await conn.run_sync(self.Base.metadata.drop_all)

    async def get_db(self):
        db = self.SessionLocal()
        try:
            yield db
        finally:
            await db.close()
```

**Synchronous Session Initialization:**

```py
class OrmService:
    def __init__(self, db_type: str = "postgresql", config_params: dict = None):
        self.Base = declarative_base()
        self.config = ConfigFactory(db_type=db_type).get_config()
        self.config_url = self.config(**config_params).get_engine_url()
        self.engine = create_engine(self.config_url)

    def create_all(self):
        self.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)

    def drop_all(self):
        self.Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=self.engine)

    def get_db(self) -> Session:
        try:
            session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
            return session()
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

**Controller and Service for Async Version:**

```py
@Controller("finance")
class FinanceController:

    @Get("/transactions")
    async def get_transactions(self, session: AsyncSession = Depends(config.get_db)):
        stmt = select(Transaction)
        query = await session.execute(stmt)
        return query.scalars().all()
```

**Controller and Service for Sync Version:**

```py
@Controller("transaction", prefix="transaction")
class TransactionController:
    service: TransactionService = Depends(TransactionService)

    @Get("/")
    def get_transactions(self):
        return self.service.get_transactions()

@lru_cache()
class TransactionService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.orm_config = config
        self.session = self.orm_config.get_db()

    def get_transactions(self):
        return self.session.query(TransactionEntity).first()
```

**Test Procedure:**

I am using the following test script to send 1000 requests to both versions:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time

async def fetch(session, url):
    start_time = time.time()
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        response_text = await response.text()
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"URL: {url} - Start: {start_time:.2f}, End: {end_time:.2f}, Duration: {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds")
    return response_text

async def main():
    s = time.time()
    urls = ["http://0.0.0.0:8088/transactions"] * 1000
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [fetch(session, url) for url in urls]
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(len(responses))
        print("response have been gathered")
    print(f"Total time: {time.time() - s:.2f}")

# Run the main coroutine
asyncio.run(main())
```

**Question:**

I am puzzled by the vast difference in performance between the two versions. The asynchronous version, which I expected to be faster or at least comparable in performance, is significantly slower. What could be causing such a disparity in performance between the synchronous and asynchronous versions of the same application?

Any insights or suggestions on what might be contributing to this issue and how to optimize the asynchronous version would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You query all by async, but query first by sync.

Comment: I have the very same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Not for this one, but i do noticed that the async feature is extremely meaningful, especially when you have extensive queries that can stuck the whole api