# Why is an asynchronous SQLAlchemy query slower than a synchronous one?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Good afternoon, I have a fastapi project that uses SQLAlchemy ORM. I noticed that the same request runs in different times if it is launched synchronously and asynchronously. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

```
Python==3.11
psyconpg-binary==2.9.7
asyncpg==0.28.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.25
```

Script

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from pyinstrument import Profiler
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, String, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, Session, mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):  # type:ignore
    pass


class Device(Base):
    __tablename__ = "device"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    date_created: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime())
    mac: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50))


stmt = select(Device).where(Device.mac.in_(["ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff"]))


def foo1():
    t = datetime.now()
    engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@localhost:5432/db_name")
    with Session(engine) as session:
        result = session.execute(stmt).all()
    engine.dispose()
    print("Execute first synchronous query ", (datetime.now() - t).microseconds * 0.001)

    t = datetime.now()

    with Session(engine) as session:
        result = session.execute(stmt).all()
    engine.dispose()
    print("Execute second synchronous query ", (datetime.now() - t).microseconds * 0.001)


async def foo2():
    t = datetime.now()

    engine = create_async_engine("postgresql+asyncpg://user:password@localhost:5432/db_name")
    async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)
    async with async_session() as session:
        result = await session.execute(stmt)
    await engine.dispose()
    print("Execute first asynchronous query ", (datetime.now() - t).microseconds * 0.001)

    t = datetime.now()
    profiler = Profiler(async_mode="enabled")
    profiler.start()
    async with async_session() as session:
        result = await session.execute(stmt)
    await engine.dispose()
    profiler.stop()
    print(profiler.print())
    print("Execute second asynchronous query ", (datetime.now() - t).microseconds * 0.001)


foo1()
asyncio.run(foo2())
```

Output. Time in milliseconds.

```
Execute first synchronous query  48.031
Execute second synchronous query  7.0600000000000005
Execute first asynchronous query  47.852000000000004
Execute second asynchronous query  29.87
```

Profiler

```
0.043 MainThread  <thread>:140457073989440
├─ 0.042 <module>  test.py:1
│  └─ 0.042 run  asyncio/runners.py:160
│        [25 frames hidden]  asyncio, hmac, <built-in>, re, asyncp...
│           0.040 Handle._run  asyncio/events.py:78
│           │  0.033 _SelectorSocketTransport._read_ready__data_received  asyncio/selector_events.py:991
│           │  ├─ 0.011 [self]  asyncio/selector_events.py
│           ├─ 0.006 foo2  test.py:44
│           │  ├─ 0.003 AsyncSession.execute  sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py:429
│           │  │     [17 frames hidden]  sqlalchemy, asyncpg, asyncio
│           │  ├─ 0.002 AsyncEngine.dispose  sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py:1120
│           │  │     [4 frames hidden]  sqlalchemy, asyncpg
│           │  └─ 0.001 [self]  test.py
└─ 0.001 Session.execute  sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:2201
      [10 frames hidden]  sqlalchemy
```

I tried changing the connection configuration, but everything remained unchanged.
I saw the question([Why is Synchronous SQLAlchemy Session Faster than Asynchronous in FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523188/why-is-synchronous-sqlalchemy-session-faster-than-asynchronous-in-fastapi)), but there is no answer there.

Comment: In your second case you're counting all the time setting up the profiler as well: `t = datetime.now()` is before `profiler = Profiler(async_mode="enabled")`, so you're not timing the same thing. Timing for the first query is the same where there is no profiler enabled in foo2. You'll have to run them with the same setup at least.

Comment: Also, it's better to use `time.monotonic()` to measure time.